# Ожидание завершения работы сборщика мусора

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Как проверить состояние сборщика мусора в определенный момент времени? Из-за того, что (насколько я понимаю) он работает в другом потоке - вызов System.gc(); не ожидает завершения работы и сразу переходит к следующему оператору.

```
Test a;
    for (int i=0;i++<10;) a = new Test(); // Тут я перезаписываю в одну ссылку много объектов дабы потом использовать сборщик
    System.gc(); // Вызов сборщика
    System.out.println(Test.geta()); // Выведение статичной переменной a (количество обьектов), должно выводить 0, но выводит 10
```

Код представленный ниже - из класса Test, в переменной а (статическая, приватная) хранится количество объектов этого типа на данный момент времени

```
Test(){
    ++a; 
// ...
}

protected void finalize() {
    // ...
    --a;
}
```

Comment: Переносимого способа нет.

Answer (score 1):

Метод finalize может быть вызван тогда, когда gc захочет. Может и никогда. У Вас нет официального способа так просто его заставить вызываться. Java имеет полное право игнорировать вызов gc. Хотите больше контроля - пишите свой gc или переходите на другие языки